# Number of times a value appears (sql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, duplicates

I'm currently working on a PostgreSQL server. Given a table containing:

```
New Jersey | Male
New Jersey | Female
New York   | Male
```

I want to return something that looks like:

```
New Jersey | Male   | 2
New Jersey | Female | 2
New York   | Male   | 1
```

I basically want to know how many times New Jersey or New York appears in the table, regardless of whether it's male or female. I also don't want to get rid of any rows. Any solution around this? Thanks!

Comment: It is rather confusing that state names are put into the city_name column.

Answer (score 2):

You need window function :

```
select t.*, count(city_name) over (partition by city_name)
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
SELECT state,
       gender,
       COUNT(1) OVER
         ( PARTITION BY state) fieldYouWant
  FROM Your_Table
```

Answer (score 0):

just a thought you can also use sub-query and aggregate funtion

```
   select distinct t1.*,t2.cnt as count from t t1
    inner join
    (
    select city_name, count(*) as cnt from t
    group by city_name
    ) as t2 on t1.city_name=t2.city_name
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/af578/1

```
city_name   gender  count
New York    Male    1
New Jersey  Female  2
New Jersey  Male    2
```